# execute different class to another

Tags: java

I'm having a really hard time to make this project to run but keep on failling....
so what I want to do is send the String or all the message that other class "bankingmain.java" to client class.
The source I create is

==========================================================================

```
package main;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class BankingMain {

public static void main(String[] args)throws IOException {


    ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(9000);
    System.out.println("Server is waiting");

    while(true) {
    Socket s = ss.accept();
    InetSocketAddress clientip = 
    (InetSocketAddress)s.getRemoteSocketAddress();
    System.out.println
    (clientip.getHostString() + " client has connected");
    try{

        OutputStream stream = s.getOutputStream();

        stream.write(bak);
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    InputStream is = s.getInputStream();
    byte b [] = new byte[100];
    int cnt = is.read(b);
    String input = new String(b, 0, cnt); 
    System.out.println
    ("client ip = " + input);
              OutputStream os = s.getOutputStream();
            input = input+"(input)";
            byte b2[] = input.getBytes();
            os.write(b2);
    }
}
```

}

===========================================================
this is gonna be a server

and the method that I', trying to exeicute and print it out to client will be below

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("************************************************");
    System.out.println("1. login\t\t2. id / find password");
    //System.out.println("2. id/find password");
    System.out.println("3. signup\t\t4. quit");
    //System.out.println("4. quit");
    System.out.println("************************************************");     
    System.out.print("put number: ");

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    String menu = sc.nextLine();
    if (menu.equals("1") || menu.equals("login")) {
        new view.LoginView().input();
    }
    else if (menu.equals("2") || menu.equals("id") || menu.equals("password") || menu.equals("find")) {
        new view.MemberSearchView().input();
    }
    else if (menu.equals("3") || menu.equals("signup")) {
        new view.MemberInsertView().input();
    }
    else if (menu.equals("4") || menu.equals("quit")) System.exit(0);
    else System.out.println();
        }

}
```

there are a vo,dao that everything runs fine but when I'm trying to extend to be server and client it doesn't work that I assume...

I am stuck in this part... help me out

Comment: Could you split your code into parts. I really do not understnad what's wrong. Too many lines there. And it is not compilable this time.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to send, and which method are you sending it to? Have you attempted to do so in your code but it isn't working, or do you need help figuring out how to start doing this?